# How do I hide data from one controller but share it with another controller using a shared service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-services, angular-controller

I just discovered how to share data between controllers using a service that stores an array and passes it by reference to the second controller.

Is there a way that the Service can protect the array from the first controller as that controller is only required pass an item to the service. The array is only used by the second controller.

- `ModalController` - accepts input from user
- `MyService` - takes the input from the user and stores it in an array -
- `ActionController` - has a reference to the MyService array and displays it on the view

Above is the basic structure of the app.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ntm1sw4f/1/) is a jsfiddle of it

Comment: Please, provide the actual code for what you're trying to do. Code descriptions never work. It isn't clear what 'hide' and 'protect' refer to. Who do you 'protect' this data from and why?

Comment: Sorry, I have added a jsfiddle to the edited question. I am wondering if there is a way of preventing the ModalCtrl from having access to the array.

Comment: There is not really a concept of 'protection' in the way that you mean. There are no private variables in Javascript. Things are only hidden by context. If you don't want your controller to access the array... just don't access the array in that controller.

Comment: As said above, there's no way to do that and I cannot think of a good reason to do that. Explaining why you would need to do that in the first place would help. What will happen if you won't prevent the controller? Since the service has public interface, any controller or whatever can use `passChore`. You could create an another service with limited functionality that wraps this one and doesn't expose `passChore` method... but what for?

Comment: I was just wondering. Not something I am looking to do. Considering concepts like encapsulation and data hiding. I figured that since the ModalCtrl doesn't need to access the array, it would be good practice to prevent it from accessing the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're overdoing it. This cannot be done by means of the framework, and this cannot be solved by means of JavaScript, since the language has no access control.

`MyService` has both `getChore` and `passChore` methods as its public interface, and any unit that uses the service can both methods too. This is perfectly fine. If both controllers are developed by yourself and you have no real reasons to restrict the access, apply Occam's razor here and don't look any further.

If this were a library that is developed by you and will be used by third party, a method that shouldn't be used from the outside could be marked as 'internal' and named accordingly. AngularJS  has the convention to prefix all internal things with `$$`.

On the other hand, TypeScript is intended to augment JavaScript with types and access control, so is possible to solve it this way, at least at design time (before TS source code was compiled to JS):

```
interface IWritableFooService {
    setFoo();
}

interface IDuplexFooService extends IWritableFooService {
    getFoo();
}

class FooService implements IDuplexFooService {
    getFoo() {...}
    setFoo() {...}
}
```

Considering that the service was defined as

```
app.service('fooService', FooService);
```

It can be injected in one place with restrictive type:

```
app.controller('BarController', function (fooService: IWritableFooService) {...});
```

And with loose type in another:

```
app.controller('BazController', function (fooService: IDuplexFooService) {...});
```

If `BarController` will try to use `fooService.getFoo()`, this will result in TypeScript compilation error.

This approach is an example of overengineering. Even if proper interface was specified, nobody can prohibit a developer to replace `IWritableFooService` with `IDuplexFooService` type at some point. OOP best practices originate from practical considerations, and it appears that there's none. But yes, it is possible to do this with TypeScript.